# Do we need [privileges] and [permissions]?

Tags: discussion, retag-request

I don't think we need either, but at the very least, [privileges](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/privileges) should be merged into [permissions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/permissions) (or the other way around).

Comment: Personally I think `[permissions]` is fine to keep, but we should probably merge `[file-permissions]` and `[effective-permissions]` into that.

Comment: @slhck: Heh, and here I was thinking the more specific `[file-permissions]` is better. But, yeah, I'll take whatever merge I can get ;D

Comment: I think [file-permissions] should be the top level as well, to stop it being used for login/active directory permissions etc

Comment: Create and symlink them all to `[access-control]`

Comment: I'd say no need for [privileges], [effective-permissions], [access-control]. [permissions] is a subsection of security, and it covers it all so keep [permissions], but since their are lots of [file-permission] questions might as well keep that tag too.

Comment: Privileges in Windows are different from permissions.
Permissions are rights to do things to specific objects (they appear in a "permissions list", or DACL, that's a property of an object). Privileges otoh are rights to do certain things that don't pertain to particular objects, like "set system time" or "take ownership of any object". They are also called "user rights". One uses the Group Policy Editor to grant them to accounts or groups. 
So if the terms are used correctly they very definitely provide useful information as to what is being talked about.